# React dynamic component from array

Tags: reactjs

I have an list of menu:

```
import { HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'

export const menus = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    to: '/',
    desc: 'Hello!',
    icon: HomeIcon,
  },
  //...
]
```

I render this array in component like this:

```
{menus.map(menu => (
    <li key={menu.to}>
        {DynamicComponent(menu.icon)}
    </li>
))}
```

method `DynamicComponent`:

```
const DynamicComponent = (Component: any) => <Component />
```

React dont rendering any icon. How I can render dynamic component using data from array?

Comment: Maybe use `children` prop?

Comment: I don't understand the need for `DynamicComponent` at all, if `HomeIcon` is already a component, why not just include `menu.icon` directly in the list item?

Comment: @DBS when I render just: `{menu.icon}` Gatsby return me error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Well, if `menu.icon` isn't a component, what are you expecting it to be used for when you pass it in as "Component" in `(Component: any) => ...`?

Comment: @michal I’d think you’d want to use ‘<menu.icon>’ and not ‘{menu.icon}’. For starters, try hard coding ‘<HomeIcon>’ and make sure that works. If it doesn’t, your issue is with that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@crosen9999 gave me a hint. I render just:

```
{menus.map(menu => (
    <li key={menu.to}>
        <menu.icon className="w-5 h-5" />
    </li>
))}
```